# Pointer to array dilemma

Tags: c++, c, pointer-arithmetic

I have a rather simple question about arrays and pointer to arrays.
consider this code fragment..

```
int (*ptr)[3];               //A pointer to an array of 3 ints
int arr1[3] = {2,4,6,};      
ptr = &arr1;                //ptr now points to arr1

//3 different ways to express  the same address
cout << &arr1 << "\t" << arr1 << "\t" << &arr1[0] << endl;
```

Now if:

```
&arr1 == arr1 == &arr1[0]..
```

why is this code not correct:

```
ptr = arr1;
```

or

```
ptr = &arr1[0];
```

This has been driving me crazy...so please any explanation would be appreciated. Also please not that this is not an homework question, just something I'm trying to get a grips on.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810668/46642) explains that.

Comment: I find [this C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) explains this clearly.  It is part of [a larger section on arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys...that explains a lot.. :-D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

In

```
ptr = arr1;
```

`arr1` is converted to an `int*`, so you're trying to assign from an incompatible pointer type. `&arr1[0]` is directly an `int*`, without conversion, so again incompatible.

```
&arr1 == arr1 == &arr1[0]
```

is wrong, since the entities have different types. They only point to the same address, so when printing out, they give the same result.

Comment: `arr1` doesn't _point_ at anything, it's an array.  It simply _implicitly converts_ to a pointer to it's own address.

Comment: @MooingDuck Right you are, I meant after the conversion to an `int*` it points to the same address as the other two expressions.

Answer (score 3):

In most contexts, an expression with an array type is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of such array, as explained by 6.3.2.1p3:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *array of type* is converted to an expression with type *pointer to type* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Thus the right-hand side of your assignment

```
ptr = arr1;
```

is implicitly converted to an incompatible pointer type (`int*` vs. `int (*)[3]`), and can't be stored to the pointer variable without a cast.

This isn't really an exception to any rule, as you need to use the unary `&` operator with other types, too:

```
T val, *ptr;
ptr = &val;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Below programme will help you to better understand difference between 
>       pointer_to_first_member_of_array, pointer_to_1D_array, pointer_to_2D_array.
>       Please carefully look at the programme, execute it and see output.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int priv_element = 88;

int array[2][5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

int next_element = 99;

main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int *ptr_to_first_element = &array[0][0];

  int (*ptr_to_1d_arry)[5] = &array[0];

  int (*ptr_to_2d_arry)[2][5] = &array;

  printf ("Print first num of first array of 2-Dim array: %d\n",
      *ptr_to_first_element);

  ptr_to_first_element += 5;

  printf ("Print first num of second array of 2-Dim array: %d\n",
      *ptr_to_first_element);

  printf ("Print first num of first array of 2-Dim array: %d\n",
      (*ptr_to_1d_arry)[0]);

  ptr_to_1d_arry++;

  printf ("Print first num of second array of 2-Dim array: %d\n",
      (*ptr_to_1d_arry)[0]);

  printf ("Print first num of first array of 2-Dim array: %d\n",
      (*ptr_to_2d_arry)[0][0]);

  ptr_to_2d_arry++;

  printf
    ("Now you increased to point end of 2d-array space. So next to it is next_element on data-seg: %d\n",
     (*ptr_to_2d_arry)[0][0]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you printed the various expressions, it showed you that their **values** were the same. However, they do not have the same **types**.

C and C++ include type features to reduce human mistakes and to make it easier to write complicated code. Suppose you had an address in some pointer p and C/C++ allowed you to do either:

```
float *f = p;
```

or:

```
int *i = p;
```

This would be a mistake, because, generally, whatever bits are in the memory at p do not represent both a useful int and a useful float. By enforcing rules about types, the language prevents a programmer from making a mistake here; the pointer p can only be assigned to another pointer of a compatible type, unless the programmer explicitly overrides the rules with a cast.

Similarly, your `ptr` is a pointer to an array of three `int`. At first, it might seem like your `arr1` is also an array of three int, so you should be able to assign `ptr = arr1;`. This is wrong because `ptr` is merely a pointer, but `arr1` is an entire array object. You cannot put an entire array into a pointer; you need to put a pointer to the array into the pointer. To get a pointer to the array, you use the `&` operator: `ptr = &arr1;`.

Another thing that is confusing here is that C/C++ includes an automatic shortcut: It converts an array to a pointer to the first element of the array. When `arr1` appears in most contexts, it is changed automatically to `&arr1[0]`. There is not a huge philosophical reason for this; it is just a convenience for the ways we often use arrays. So `ptr = arr1;` would be equivalent to `ptr = &arr1[0];`, which is also not allowed. In this form, you can see that `arr1` has become a pointer to an int, so you cannot assign it to a pointer to an array of int. Even though the pointer has the **value** you want, it is the wrong **type**.

When an array appears as the operand of `&` or `sizeof` or `_Alignof`, this automatic conversion does not occur. So `&arr1` results in the address of the array.

A string literal that is used in an initialization such as `char a[] = "abc";` is treated specially and is not automatically converted as described above.